# need advice with passing a javascript value into html format so i can show a grade screen of correct answers instead of 'document.write'

Tags: javascript, html, database, sqlite

below is the code for the check function that will store the value of the 'c' variable and the `document.write` will display it in a empty page. i have been trying to find a way to pass this into my html so i can create a grading screen and display the same line i have here into a html format but i cannot get the function or variable to pass through however i try.

```
function check() {
  let c=0
  const q1=document.quiz.question1.value
  const q2=document.quiz.question2.value
  const q3=document.quiz.question3.value
  const q4=document.quiz.question4.value
  const q5=document.quiz.question5.value
  if(q1==='1') {
    c++
  }
  if(q2==='1') {
    c++
  }
  if(q3==='1') {
    c++
  }
  if(q4==='1') {
    c++
  }
  if(q5==='1') {
    c++
  }
  document.write('<h1>You scored ' + c + ' 
and your average was ' + c/10*100 + '%</h1>')
}
```

below is the html code i tried but i don't understand how to export the function parameters

```
<section>
    <h2> Welcome
    <script type="text/javascript">
       document.write('You scored ' + c + 
'and your average was ' + c/10*100 + '%' ")
    </script>
    </h2>
  </section>
```

i know that this may not be part of the question or may be an additional step, but would it be easier to store that c value into a database and then pull from the database into the html code? i need to be able to store that score along with a name into a database anyways so maybe it would be easier to populate the database with the values and then take them out of there with a select query or handlebar tag (as i have a index.handlebar that i will be displaying the scores on with other data). sorry for the long question but i've been struggling with the database side so need to quickly solve these issues. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Sorry for the long amounts of code but i wasn't sure what you needed to undertand what im trying to do. The code below saves the value within the radio button and the variable c auto-increments +1 and then the function at the bottom called "check3()" runs the increment for every value and then it runs the calculation. what i want to do is display that same statement calculation in the same page if needed but it will need to have the same css as the page of the current page.

```
  <main class='questionsContainer'>
    <form name='quiz' id='quiz'>
      <!-- first set -->
      <section id='questions6' style="min-height: 190px">
        <h3>{{this.Question1}}</h3>               
        <!-- first choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option1" name="question1" value="0">Emacs</h3>

        <!-- second choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option2" name="question1" value="0">Notepad++</h3>

        <!-- third choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option3" name="question1" value="1">Vim</h3>

        <!-- fourth choice -->
      <h3><input type="radio" id="option4" name="question1" value="0">Bash</h3><br>
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px;" type='button' onclick="nextQuestion(6, 7)">next</button>
    </section>

    <!-- second set -->
    <section id='questions7' style="min-height: 190px">
        <h2>{{this.Question2}}</h2>
        <!-- first choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option1" name="question2" value="1">Nothing</h3>

        <!-- second choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option2" name="question2" value="0">
          Java Development Kit 1.8 or newer</h3>

        <!-- third choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option3" name="question2" value="0">Apache Maven</h3>

        <!-- fourth choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option4" name="question2" value="0">
          Jakarta Enterprise Edition web profile compliant server</h3><br>

        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; left: 35%;" type='button' onclick="previousQuestion(7, 6)">previous</button>
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px;" type='button' onclick="nextQuestion(7, 8)">next</button>
    </section>



    <!-- Third set -->
    <section id='questions8' style="min-height: 190px">
        <h2>{{this.Question3}}</h2>
        <!-- first choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option1" name="question3" value="0">username and IP address</h3>

        <!-- second choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option2" name="question3" value="0">username and password</h3>

        <!-- third choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option3" name="question3" value="0">email address and password</h3>

        <!-- fourth choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option4" name="question3" value="1">username and email address</h3><br>
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; left: 35%;" type='button' onclick="previousQuestion(8, 7)">previous</button>
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px;" type='button' onclick="nextQuestion(8, 9)">next</button>
    </section>

    <!-- fourth set -->
    <section id='questions9' style="min-height: 190px"style="min-height: 190px">
        <h2>{{this.Question4}}</h2>
        <!-- first choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option1" name="question4" value="0">System</h3>

        <!-- second choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option2" name="question4" value="0">Local</h3>

        <!-- third choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option3" name="question4" value="1">User</h3>

        <!-- fourth choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option4" name="question4" value="0">Global</h3><br>
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; left: 35%;" type='button' onclick="previousQuestion(9, 8)">previous</button>
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px;" type='button' onclick="nextQuestion(9, 10)">next</button>
    </section>

    <!-- fifth set -->
    <section id='questions10' style="min-height: 190px">
        <h2>{{this.Question5}}</h2>
        <!-- first choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option1" name="question5" value="0">Junio C. Hamano</h3>

        <!-- second choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option2" name="question5" value="0">James Gosling</h3>

        <!-- third choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option3" name="question5" value="1">Linus Torvalds</h3>

        <!-- fourth choice -->
        <h3><input type="radio" id="option4" name="question5" value="0">Kohsuke Kawaguchi</h3> <br>
      
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; left: 25%;"
        type='button' onclick="previousQuestion(10, 9)">previous</button>
      
        <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; left: 35%;" type='button' 
        onclick="nextQuestion(10, 6)">Back to Question 1</button>

      <input style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; right:20%;" type="button" 
             value="Check Your Grade!" onclick="check3(check1, check2)">
    </section>
    {{/each}}
    </form>
    </main>
```

Comment: Where is your JavaScript? Is it in a separate JS file?

Comment: yes i have imported the javascript file to make use of some button functions that hide and show elements, i have tried to import the variable using inline code within the main tag itself and it has not worked. i know the file has been imported correcly becauuse the buttons work completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to take the document.write and display that on the screen.

```
function myFunction() {
//Create the HTML ELEMENT 
const msgDiv = document.createElement('h1');

// create the message you want to display
 msgDiv.innerHTML = `<span>$ You scored {c} and you average was {c/10*100}%</span>$`;

// Display that message by appending it to an HTML element

 yourHTMLELEMENTWHEREYOUWANTITTODISPLAY.appendChild(msgDiv);
```

}

```
//call the function 
myFunction()

//add an eventlistener on function
button.addEventListener('click', myFunction)


You have your quiz wrapped in a form, so you can just add an add event listener on that element. That way when the quiz is at the end and when someone hits submit the other function to display the results can run. Also you want to have the form submit so that they can either click or hit enter so submit. 




 form.addEventListener('submit' (e) => {
   // this stops the page from submitting and going to another page
   e.preventDefault();
   // Add the code from up above. 
   // You don't want your check function to be in this code because it will only run when the form is submitted and you don't want that.
})
```

Comment: how would i call that function? would i only create that function in the js file and then call in into html? im kind of new to html and js so i'm trying to understand how things work.

Comment: You usually want to keep you javascript and html separate. You would access the javascript by having a script file located in the html file like this <script src="main.js"></script>

Comment: And to call the function it, you would call it like this myFunction(), You could also add an event listener so that it is only called when someone performs an action like click, or mouseover

Comment: @Yusuf Hanif There are multiple ways to add an event listener to a function. It is worth looking at the javascript document to help you out.

Comment: The only issue with event listener is that i was advised not to ise jquery. Not sure if jquery would make things more difficult or easier but i have to refrain from it. I will also try to find a way to make it work. Thanks

Comment: @YusufHanif I don't use jquery so don't know about that but the event listener is also a javascript method.

Comment: OK i can see that the event listener is a javascript method but i'm having some trouble trying to implement it.. Would you be able to clarify what goes into the HTMl and what goes into the JS file. i have tried many different methods of trying to import the stored variables but i have had no luck. i also wanted to clarify that the variables are stored as values in a html page called 'Questions.html' that are then stored into the javascript function and then i will need to pull those same values from the javascript variable. im struggling to get anything to work.

Comment: @YusufHanif Can you post your HTML?

Comment: yeah sorry i forgot to add the html code yesterday but i have just edited it and you can see the bottom paragraph above the last block of code

Comment: @YusufHanif You don't need the button to have an add event listener because you are submitting the form instead.

Comment: ok sorry i'm still having trouble because i've checked so many docs and videos that i'm not sure what's needed in the HTML page and what is needed in the Questions.js file which is where the check() function is located.

Comment: You have everything you need. You are just pulling HTML elements to the javascript file so that you can manipulate them. You just store them in variable so that the javascript can help you perform actions on them when you interact with those elements.

Comment: Is you js file connected to your HTML file?

Comment: yes, well its a hbs but its a template given to me by my teacher, it runs html. my questions.js file connected already as i have the document.write already running as 
well as the check functions when the "check grades" button is clicked.

Comment: If your js file is connected, you don't need the inline javascript. You can put all of the js in one file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226796/discussion-between-yusuf-hanif-and-alanaj).